# Mathematical proofs in non-math paper: What if they are wrong?

Tags: publications, advisor

So my first paper from my undergraduate research just got published! Yay!

However: I am still stressed out: What if there were any mistakes? I did my undergraduate research in a psychology lab, all other coauthors have a psychology background. I myself got very interested in mathematical modeling and took many math classes as an undergrad. As a result the paper also had a lot of mathematical statements and proofs in the supplement. Nobody except me has ever checked the proofs. They passed through peer review; though I am not too sure the reviewers were in a position to judge the proofs either (unless the editor was very diligent and sent the manuscript to mathematicians; it did not sound like that from the reviews).

To the best of my ability these proofs are correct. However, I would not describe myself a mathematician yet (though I will start my PhD in the fall in an applied math department), so I am worried there could be some subtle error in there.

What would my current advisor think if someone actually found a mistake there? Or my future department? Are such thoughts common and how do people deal with these?

Comment: As far as the last part goes, yes, these thoughts are very common.  Many researchers or other high achievers suffer from impostor syndrome for a significant portion of their career (up to and including 100% of it).  I still spend a few minutes a week, at least, imagining someone significant telling me that every thing I've ever done is wrong and deeply flawed.  I'm hoping to one day graduate to just imagining people telling me that every thing I've ever done was easy and wholly unremarkable (but at least correct).  Years of this never happening, plus therapy, can be helpful.

Comment: Even without invoking impostor's syndrome, it is very common for papers to be published with errors, even by very prominent researchers. In fact, it would probably be a good sign if someone finds an error in your paper: it means they found it interesting enough to pay attention.

Comment: This is something you should've worried about *before* the paper was published.  Keep this feeling in mind as a learning experience: yes, mistakes happen, but don't try to publish papers before you're confident in them.

Comment: In future, you could address this by actually asking some mathematician to look at your paper before you submit it, especially if you don't think the peer review process will include that.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I welcome someone to tell me that everything I've done is wrong or flawed. The sooner I correct my mistakes the better! Until then, I'm going to do the best I can, making what decisions I can based on the information available to me. If the next Einstein feels my work is important enough to correct, well dammit that's a good problem to have.

Comment: @corsiKa Shortly put, a person with impostor syndrome, or other relevant disorder, is not going to view things that way.  Yours is the view of a fairly well-adjusted person.  Which is not the kind of person I was referencing.  Though hopefully the OP, and many others, develop towards the well-adjusted perspective in relatively short order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are probably right: it seems unlikely that mathematical statements and proofs included in the supplementary materials to a psychology paper would receive much scrutiny.  Even if the editor took the time out to get an extra, mathematically sophisticated referee, the fact that you received no comments about this part of the paper (right?) indicates that even if "read" it was not regarded as an important factor in the evaluation of the paper.

What is the upshot of this?  In a nutshell: for better and/or for worse, probably this mathematical work of yours will receive little or no attention.  I don't know any mathematicians who regularly read psychology literature.  Since you have just been admitted to a PhD program in mathematics, the time for people to scrutinize your undergraduate research has already mostly passed.  By the time you graduate, you should/will have much more relevant material for people to focus on.  It is debatable whether you should even list this paper on your CV at the end of your graduate career: I would say you probably should, but in a separate category from all of your math papers.

If I were looking to hire you for a post-PhD academic position, I honestly would not even consider reading a psychology paper you wrote as an undergraduate.  I would not expect such a paper to have any substantial mathematical contributions, I would expect to be entirely unable to evaluate the significance of the paper as a work of psychology, and -- more honestly -- knowing that you put some theorems and proofs in it as an unassisted undergraduate student, I would expect this material to be a bit callow/superficial.  Most undergraduates have not begun to independently engage in research-level mathematics *in any way*, so it is hard to hold against them whatever they put in papers.

Viewing this as a teachable moment, here are some possible takeaways:

1) I agree with Kimball and Nate Eldredge: you should do what you need to do to gather confidence in your work *before you publish it*.  By professional mathematical standards, yes, it is a mistake to publish a piece of mathematics without soliciting the opinion of at least one mathematically qualified person.  If you happen to be in a similar situation in the future, you should show your work to teachers and mentors in the mathematics department.  You may have to wait what seems like a long time to get a fairly quick reading / reaction from them, but even an instantaneous reaction is valuable.

2) On the other hand, just because you're worried doesn't mean you actually did anything wrong, and it certainly doesn't mean that you did anything *terribly* wrong.  A large percentage of papers contain minor errors.  E.g. just yesterday I got an email from a collaborator informing me of a typo in a published paper (on the same subject as our collaboration, but he was not a coauthor).  There was a missing "+1" from several formulas.  This really doesn't distress me at all: I will make the change on the copy of the paper on my own webpage, and that's that.  And by the way, I have made worse mistakes than this in published work (and in my PhD thesis): ones that do bother me a bit, but much more me than anyone else.  In the realm of honest mistakes, I can't think of what you could have done in an undergraduate paper in a different field that would be so bad so as to place any clouds in the sky of your academic career.

3) Let me not completely neglect the possibility that you did something right: maybe your paper has a real mathematical contribution.  If that is the case, you should not drop the matter but try to continue, improve and refine the work, with the goal of publishing it elsewhere.  Again, mathematics hidden in a psychology paper is very well hidden indeed.  Maybe that's not what you or the mathematical community wants.

Comment: I would think you should notify the editor of the journal this paper of yours was published in, and let them decide on issuing a corrigendum.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! Indeed, I could try refining this and submitting it in a mathematical journal as a side-project during my PhD. (If I don't find any terrible mistakes in there by then.)

Comment: @phdhopeful Just don't run afoul of double publishing/self plagiarism if you try to do that.  The basic advice would be not to bother, unless you can come up with legitimate new contributions (either from a math standpoint or a psychology standpoint), in which case you either have a follow up paper, or a paper with no official relation but just happened to have been inspired by a line of thought connected to the old one.  You can consult with your future advisor on how to proceed if, as Pete suggests, there seems to be worthwhile math buried well outside the field.

Comment: @zibadawa: If I understand the OP correctly, he has not found a mistake.  He's just concerned that he may possibly have made a mistake (somewhere) in the paper.  If I have that right, I think it would not be a good idea to notify the editor.

Comment: I think zibadawa was talking about *your* typo, Pete.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Chris is correct.

Answer (score 2):

We live in a 'post publication peer review' world, where every paper you publish can be, and usually is, scrutinized by your peers. This sometimes sounds daunting, but you can also make this work in your advantage. In this specific case, you could ask one or two experts in the field of mathematics to review the material that is available. If they find that it is accurate... great! If they find that there are errors, you can proactively publish an corrigendum to rectify the mistakes made.

Your responsibility for this paper does not stop once it was published. The author remains responsible and should proactively seek out improvements, where possible and relevant.

It is great that you have raised this, it shows that you are committed to the work that you have published and want to present it in the best way possible.

Good luck...